# Is there a Google Apps Script quotas dashboard?

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

Does Google offer any type of dashboard which shows which scripts are using the most amount of computer time? I've been getting a lot of notices lately that I'm exceeding my computer time quota. I'm making adjustments where I can but it's difficult to know where I can tweak things without some type of dashboard showing me where my quota is being used.

Comment: You can check the quota for emails within Apps Script [Link Apps Script documentation - getRemainingDailyQuota()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#getRemainingDailyQuota())  But other than that, I can't find any "built-in" way to check current quotas.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to check quotas. Some of the service APIs may have methods (like [MailApp's getRemainingDailyQuota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#getRemainingDailyQuota())). You can also check the [Quotas page from your Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/quotas). Sometimes you get quota errors that are unclear but there is a [reference page that clarifies some of them](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages).